Lost calculation
A couple did a couple of calculations, but lost the last one ...
Can you recover the result?
345  53507  514  4914  ?

Hint: (unhide if you want to see 4 possible options)

 3045, 7334, 7718, 7738


ǝlzznd ǝɔıN

When answering this puzzle, it would help to visualise these numbers...

 ...as if written on a calculator (hence the references to 'calculation' in the title and flavour-text). Thus, 345 53507 514 4914 becomes:



Now - as a schoolchild might commonly do with this object when having some fun...

 ...turn it upside down!



 Now, when each number is rotated 180 degrees, they appear to spell words: SHE, LOSES, HIS and HIGH.

What might follow this?

 A natural answer that can be spelled out in the same fashion could be 7334, which upside-down becomes HEEL, giving us the phrase: SHE LOSES HIS HIGH HEEL.



 Note that this phrases uses both 'she' and 'his', suggesting a male-female 'couple' are involved in this narrative, as per the flavour-text. The pair of high heels also make up another 'couple' in this story.

 (NB This number is also one of the options given in the hint...)

Post Script:
The OP suggests in comments that this solution - albeit correct in execution - was not the intended solution number to be plucked from the list of four in the hint. So what was?

 Our four options are 3045 (yielding SHOE when rotated 180 degrees), 7334 (HEEL), 7718 (BILL) and 7738 (BELL).



 Whilst by my reckoning, inserting 'heel' into the sentence 'She loses his high [BLANK]' makes good sense (for instance, in the case of a woman having borrowed - and then mislaid - a stiletto from her male friend), the OP may instead be hoping for 7718 (BILL) here, with the calculation of the total payment on a bill or invoice underlying the story, in which the female character loses the high (pricey) bill received from - or to be given to - the male character in the narrative.


Well, you definitely found the principle! Either it was too easy or you are too experienced ;-) Unfortunately, apparently, I've chosen multiple options which somehow could make sense (which was not the original intention). Although, I didn't imagine him wearing stiletto shoes. If you check again the title, the intended option was actually a different one. Well, my formulation "possible options" is confusing, I actually wanted to say: which option of the 4 options. Of course, I will gladly accept your answer.

@theozh Re my solve path, the word 'calculation' in the text immediately sent my mind into this area. Your points noted - I've added what I suspect your intention was as a PS to my write-up :)

it's all fine! I could have put 3 "nonsense" numbers and the intended solution, but it happened all to be fully valid options that even make sense. Thank you for the nice sketches to illustrate. You are very careful!

@theozh Thanks :) I always strive to make sure my answers help others to follow the process and solve the puzzle themselves - otherwise if I just want to solve a puzzle by myself I might as well pick up a puzzle book!
